# How do I customize output of a custom type using printf?

Tags: f#, printf, string-formatting, f#-interactive

I've read through a good chunk of *Expert F#* and am working on building an actual application.  While debugging, I've grown accustomed to passing fsi commands like this to make things legible in the repl window:

```
fsi.AddPrinter(fun (x : myType) -> myType.ToString())
```

I would like to extend this to work with the printf formatter, so I could type e.g.

```
printf "%A" instanceOfMyType
```

and control the output for a custom type.  The book implies that this can be done (p 93, "Generic structural formatting can be extended to work with any user-defined data types,
a topic covered on the F# website"), but I have failed to find any references as to how to actually accomplish this.  Does anyone know how? Is it even possible?

**Edit:**

I should have included a code sample, it's a record type that I'm dealing with, e.g.

```
type myType = 
    {a: int}        
    override m.ToString() = "hello"

let t = {a=5}
printfn "%A" t
printfn "%A" (box t)
```

both print statements yield:

```
{a = 5;}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It looks like the Right Way to do this in F# 2.0 is by using the [`StructuredFormatDisplay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370334.aspx) attribute, for example:

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("hello {a}")>]
type myType = {a: int}
```

In this example, instead of the default `{a = 42;}`, you would get `hello 42`.

This works the same way for object, record, and union types. And although the pattern must be of the format `"PreText {PropertyName} PostText"` (*PreText* and *PostText* being optional), this is actually more powerful than `ToString()` because:

1. `PropertyName` can be a property of any type. If it is not a string, then it will also be subject to structured formatting. [Don Syme's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/01/08/some-tips-and-tricks-for-formatting-data-in-f-interactive-and-a-in-sprintf-printf-fprintf.aspx) gives an example of recursively formatting a tree in this way.
2. It  may be a calculated property. So you could actually get `ToString()` to work for record and union types, though in a rather round-about way:

   ```
   [<StructuredFormatDisplay("{AsString}")>]
   type myType = 
       {a: int}
       override m.ToString() = "hello"
       member m.AsString = m.ToString()  // a property that calls a method
   ```

By the way, `ToString()` will always be used (even for record and union types) if you call `printfn "%O"` instead of `printfn "%A"`.

Comment: BTW, credit to @Brian for posting these links in a follow-up comment to his answer. I just thought it was worth fleshing out for anyone else who comes looking.

Comment: The property/member can be `private` to avoid exposing possibly object allocating object properties (rather than as method invocations). Also, I was unable to make use of object methods ("was not found").

Answer (score 5):

Hmm... I vaguely recall some changes to this, but I forget if they happened before or after the CTP (1.9.6.2).

In any case, on the CTP, I see that

```
type MyType() =
    override this.ToString() = "hi"
let x = new MyType()
let xs = Array.create 25 x
printfn "%A" x
printfn "%A" xs
```

when evaluated in the VFSI window does what I would want, and that

```
x;;
xs;;
```

also prints nicely.  So, I guess I am unclear how this differs from what is desired?

Comment: Thanks; see my edit to the original post, it's a record type with a member function added, and behaves differently than a class type...

Comment: @Brian, yes, that should work, but as flatline says, it doesn't work with union and record types. I ran into this a while ago: http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/post/9163.aspx (can't remember if I sent something to fsbugs when I didn't get any followups, sorry)

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/01/08/some-tips-and-tricks-for-formatting-data-in-f-interactive-and-a-in-sprintf-printf-fprintf.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370334.aspx

Answer (score -2):

If you override ToString method, that should do.