# Foundations of F# example code does not compile, why?

Tags: f#, runtime-error

I am reading the **Foundations of F#** by Robert pickering. When I try to run the first example in the book (below) I am getting a runtime error at function print, **"Unable to parse format string 'Missing format specifier'"**

```
#mytestapp
let message = "Hello
    World\r\n\t!"
let dir = @"c:\projects"

let bytes = "bytesbytesbytes"B

let xA = 0xFFy
let xB = 0o7777un
let xC = 0b10010UL
let print x = printfn "A%" x
let main() =
    print message;
    print dir;
    print bytes;
    print xA;
    print xB;
    print xC
main()
```

**The output should be (according to the book):**

"Hello\n        World\r\n\t!"
"c:\projects"
[|98uy; 121uy; 116uy; 101uy; 115uy; 98uy; 121uy; 116uy; 101uy; 115uy; 98uy;
  121uy; 116uy; 101uy; 115uy|]
-1y
4095
18UL

I think, that maybe I don't have something referenced that I should?

Comment: I have edited printmessage to print message. That is not the error is it?

Comment: I think you might want to look at this thread; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791706/in-f-how-do-i-customize-output-of-a-custom-type-using-printf

Comment: yeah print message was a typo, A% was not that's how it is in the book and it fixed it. thank you Mauricio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your format string to be "%A", not "A%".  The format specifier comes *after* the % sign.  There's nothing after your % sign -- hence, `Missing format specifier`