# Customise FsCheck output

Tags: f#, fscheck

I am testing with FsCheck and NUnit in VisualStudio.

The problem currently is: I managed to generate random graphs (for testing some graph functionality) but when a test fails, FsCheck spits out the whole graph and it does not use ToString so it literally dumps raw list of records and you cannot see anything in there.

Also I would need not only the input graph for inspection but also some other data that I create when running a property.

So how can I change the output behaviour of FsCheck in order to

- actually call my ToString method on the input graph
- output further information

when a test fails?

EDIT:
Here is my current test setup.

```
module GraphProperties

open NUnit.Framework
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.NUnit

let generateRandomGraph =
    gen {
        let graph: Graph<int,int> = Graph<_,_>.Empty()
        // fill in random nodes and transitions...
        return graph
    }

type MyGenerators =
    static member Graph() =
        {new Arbitrary<Graph<int,int>>() with
            override this.Generator = generateRandomGraph
            override this.Shrinker _ = Seq.empty }

[<TestFixture>]
type NUnitTest() =
    [<Property(Arbitrary=[|typeof<MyGenerators>|], QuietOnSuccess = true)>]
    member __.cloningDoesNotChangeTheGraph (originalGraph: Graph<int,int>) =
        let newGraph = clone originalGraph
        newGraph = originalGraph
```

Comment: How are you doing your assertions? There are different ways to assert even when using NUnit to run tests. It would help to provide an example test, or even the last line.

Comment: I just added some code example. The hardest part was getting the generator to work. For the property itself, I get random input, call the method under test with this input and return a boolean (the result of comparison in this case).

Comment: Is `Graph<_,_>` a record or a class? Can you provide the (perhaps stripped down) definition for it? And the actual output that you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FsCheck uses `sprintf "%A"` to convert test parameters to strings in the test output, so what you need to do is control how your types are formatted by the `%A` formatter. According to [How do I customize output of a custom type using printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791706/how-do-i-customize-output-of-a-custom-type-using-printf), the way to do that is with the [`StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370334.aspx). The value of that attribute should be a string in the format `PreText {PropertyName} PostText`, where `PropertyName` should be a property (**not** a function!) on your type. E.g., let's say you have a tree structure with some complicated information in the leaves, but for your testing you only need to know about the number of leaves, not what's in them. So you'd start with a data type like this:

```
// Example 1
type ComplicatedRecord = { ... }
type Tree =
    | Leaf of ComplicatedRecord
    | Node of Tree list
    with
        member x.LeafCount =
            match x with
            | Leaf _ -> 1
            | Node leaves -> leaves |> List.sumBy (fun x -> x.LeafCount)
        override x.ToString() =
            // For test output, we don't care about leaf data, just count
            match x with
            | Leaf -> "Tree with a total of 1 leaf"
            | Node -> sprintf "Tree with a total of %d leaves" x.LeafCount
```

Now, so far that's not what you want. This type does *not* have a custom `%A` format declared, so FsCheck (and anything else that uses `sprintf "%A"` to format it) will end up outputting the whole complicated structure of the tree and all its irrelevant-to-the-test leaf data. To make FsCheck output what you want to see, you'll need to set up a *property*, not a function (`ToString` won't work for this purpose) that will output what you want to see. E.g.:

```
// Example 2
type ComplicatedRecord = { ... }
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{LeafCountAsString}")>]
type Tree =
    | Leaf of ComplicatedRecord
    | Node of Tree list
    with
        member x.LeafCount =
            match x with
            | Leaf _ -> 1
            | Node leaves -> leaves |> List.sumBy (fun x -> x.LeafCount)
        member x.LeafCountAsString = x.ToString()
        override x.ToString() =
            // For test output, we don't care about leaf data, just count
            match x with
            | Leaf -> "Tree with a total of 1 leaf"
            | Node -> sprintf "Tree with a total of %d leaves" x.LeafCount
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this in F#, just typed it into the Stack Overflow comment box -- so it's possible that I've messed up the `ToString()` part. (I don't remember, and can't find with a quick Google, whether overrides should be after or before the `with` keyword). But I know that the `StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute is what you want, because I've used this myself to get custom output out of FsCheck.

By the way, you could also have set a `StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute on the complicated record type in my example as well. For example, if you have a test where you care about the tree structure but not about the contents of the leaves, you'd write it like:

```
// Example 3
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("LeafRecord")>] // Note no {} and no property
type ComplicatedRecord = { ... }
type Tree =
    | Leaf of ComplicatedRecord
    | Node of Tree list
    with
        member x.LeafCount =
            match x with
            | Leaf _ -> 1
            | Node leaves -> leaves |> List.sumBy (fun x -> x.LeafCount)
        override x.ToString() =
            // For test output, we don't care about leaf data, just count
            match x with
            | Leaf -> "Tree with a total of 1 leaf"
            | Node -> sprintf "Tree with a total of %d leaves" x.LeafCount
```

Now all your `ComplicatedRecord` instances, no matter their contents, will show up as the text `LeafRecord` in your output, and you'll be better able to focus on the tree structure instead -- and there was no need to set a `StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute on the `Tree` type.

This isn't a totally ideal solution, as you might need to adjust the `StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute from time to time, as needed by the various tests you're running. (For some tests you might want to focus on one part of the leaf data, for others you'd want to ignore the leaf data entirely, and so on). And you'll probably want to take the attribute out before you go to production. But until FsCheck acquires a "Give me a function to format failed test data with" config parameter, this is the best way to get your test data formatted the way you need it.

Comment: Thanks, now I can print my graphs as I need to. There is one bit remaining. You mentioned that there is no way to change to output function of FsCheck. Is there really no way to somehow inherit and override the functionality (yes, this is evil OO thinking)? And does this mean that regarding the second bullet of my question, I have no chance to output e.g. the generated graph AND its clone when the test fails in my example?

Comment: If you look at the [FsCheck source code](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Runner.fs), you'll see that the `argumentsToString` function is the one calling `sprintf "%A"`, and it in turn is being called from `onFailureToString`. You can actually implement your own test runners by implementing the `IRunner` interface, so I wasn't quite right about this being the only way. It's certainly the simplest way, though.

Comment: And if you want to output the original graph and its clone, the simplest way to do that would be in your test: `let result = (originalGraph = clonedGraph); if not result then printfn "Original graph: %A" originalGraph ; printfn "Cloned graph: %A" clonedGraph; result`. Something simple like that.

Comment: Can't format code properly in comments, but the idea was that the two `printfn` calls were indented under the `if`, and the `result` line was at the function's top level of indentation. So this test returns true or false no matter what, but prints out the graph if the test fails. Alternately, and probably better, you could use a library like [Unquote](https://github.com/SwensenSoftware/unquote) to automatically print the left and right sides of a failing equality comparison.

Comment: Thank you very much for these ideas. Your links are really useful!

Comment: I would recommend limiting your use of `StructuredFormatDisplay`. It can be annoying when you remove information from the display that you want to see again, e.g. in FSI. Also the property access is not type-safe, so if you rename the property without remembering to fix the attribute then the resulting string will just contain an exception. At the very least, don't rely on it for your application logic, only tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use labels to display whatever you want when a test fails: https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/Properties.html#And-Or-and-Labels