# How to disable ToString on records

Tags: f#

I have a record type which occurs quite often in a nested complex data structure. Because the record type has an automatically generated `ToString` the `ToString` of my bigger structure becomes way to confusing and I do not care for the string representation of my record. 
So I want to have an empty string as representation for my record. Overriding `ToString` seems to not do anything, using `StructuredFormatDisplay` does not work with empty strings since it requires an input of the form `"Text {Field} Text"`. Right now I have

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{}")>]
type MyRecord
    {  5 fields... }

    override __.ToString () = ""
```

But this results in `The method MyRecord.ToString could not be found`.

So what is the correct way to not have a string representation for a record type?

Comment: I can't understand your Q, what do you mean by `Overriding ToString seems to not do anything, `?

Comment: If I override `ToString` I still get the same result as if I do not override `ToString`. In both cases `sprintf "%A" myObj` will print the default string representation

Comment: well, yeah - you have to call `myObj.ToString()` instead of `sprintf "%A" myObj`

Comment: See the accepted answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791706/how-do-i-customize-output-of-a-custom-type-using-printf — you just need an `AsString` *property* that returns `""`, then you'd do `[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{AsString}")>]`

Comment: @rmunn then it is a duplicate, right? Or maybe someone write an answer about difference between `ToString` and `sprintf`?

Comment: The `%A` format specification doesn't necessarily use `ToString()`.  To print an object using its `ToString()` method, use `%O` instead of `%A`.  See [Core.Printf Module (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.printf-module-%5bfsharp%5d).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments all provide correct information about how to achieve your goal.  Pulling it all together, here's what I would do in a real-world scenario where I wanted a record type to always have the empty string as its string representation:

```
open System

[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{StringDisplay}")>]
type MyRecord =
    {  
        A: int
        B: string
        C: decimal
        D: DateTime
        E: Guid
    }
    member __.StringDisplay = String.Empty
    override this.ToString () = this.StringDisplay
```

This way, regardless of what technique is used to print the record, or if its `ToString` method is used by an external caller, the representation will always be the same:

```
let record = {A = 3; B = "Test"; C = 5.6M; D = DateTime.Now; E = Guid.NewGuid()}
printfn "Structured Format Display:  %A" record
printfn "Implicit ToString Call:  %O" record
printfn "Explicit ToString Call:  %s" <| record.ToString()
```

This prints:

```
Structured Format Display:  
Implicit ToString Call:  
Explicit ToString Call:
```

One thing to keep in mind is that this will even override the way the record is displayed by F# interactive.  Meaning, the record evaluation itself now shows up as:

```
val record : MyRecord =
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Out of curiosity why does it display `The method MyRecord.ToString could not be found` when I use `[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{}")>]`