# ToString() override in F# doesn't work for a type containing another type

Tags: f#

I have a type 'Team' which contains another type 'Employee'. I have overridden the ToString() for the type 'Employee'. However, when I do ToString() for the type 'Team', the details from 'Employee' is pretty-printed with the standard ToString() implementation and my overriding logic was never used. Can someone help understand why the override didn't work? Here is the code:

```
type Employee =
    {
        name : string
        address : string
    }
    override this.ToString() = sprintf "Hello %s" this.name

type Team =
    {
        employee1 : Employee
    }
with member this.ToTightString =
        this.ToString().Replace(" ","")


let employee = { name="Bob"; address="Unknown"; } 
let team = {employee1=employee}
printfn "%s" (employee.ToString()) // Override works!
// OUTPUT: Hello Bob
printfn "--------------------"
printf "%s" team.ToTightString // Override doesn't work
// OUTPUT: {employee1={name="Bob";address="Unknown";};}
```

Comment: You never call the override on Employee. Try `this.employe1.ToString().Replace(" ","")` instead.

Comment: Yeah that works. Does that mean my override will work if and only if I explicitly call it with the ToString() method? Because I tried doing 
printf "%A" employee
and the ToString() was not overridden there either but was just pretty-printed!

Comment: @n7rider The simple answer is yes. It's because the default ToString implementation for a Record Type calls `sprintf`, which has special logic to output Record Types. This situation is partly because of https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/429

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer right now, but look at the [StructuredFormatDisplay attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.structuredformatdisplayattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D), which lets you specify a custom representation for `sprintf "%A" myInstance`. That might be part of what you're looking for. P.S. It looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791706/how-do-i-customize-output-of-a-custom-type-using-printf might be useful to you as well, though note that that question is from 2012.

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks. I'll create an example and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As [@rmunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314532/rmunn) has said above, the textual representation of a type (say, type1) specified in StructuredFormatDisplay is retained even if one calls ToString() on a type that contains the 'type1' type. Here's an example:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

[<StructuredFormatDisplay("name=Always Harry address={address}")>]
type Employee =
    {
        name : string
        address : string
    }

type AddressContainer = 
    {
        employee: Employee
        containerName: string
    }

let address1 = { name="Bob"; address="Random City" } 
let addressContainer1 = { employee=address1; containerName= "container1"}
printf "%s" (address1.ToString()) // prints "name=Always Harry address=Random City"
printf "%s" (addressContainer1.ToString()) // prints {employee = name=Always Harry address=Random City;  containerName = "container1";}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought this attribute only worked in FSI, but it works in my program, as well. What is the point of overriding ToString? Is there something the attribute can't do that ToString allows you to?